# Knockout Scope Issue in bindingHandlers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scope

I have a view model, MyClass, with an array property, MyList, and MyList is an object with properties like Prop1 and MySubList.

I have a `<div data-bind="with: MyClass">` in which I build a table.  I want columns of the table to be sortable, so most `<th>` look something like this:

`<th data-bind="sort: { myArray: MyList, myProperty: 'Prop1' }">Prop One</th>`

I have a ko.bindingHandler for the aforementioned `sort`, and it runs through myArray, sorting on myProperty.  This all works fine.

When it comes time to handle the entries of the `MySubList` property, I want to create a variable number of columns, one for each item in `MySubList`.

Now, from one instance of `MyClass` to another, the number of items in `MyList` can vary, but within the individual items of `MyList`, the number of items in `MySubList` is fixed, so I can reliably determine the number of columns I need from any one `MyList` item.

All these items are observable.

So, to provide the variable number of columns, I have this construct:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: MyList()[0].MySubList, as: 'subList' -->
<th data-bind="sort: { myArray: MyList, myProperty: 'SomeSubListProperty' }"></th>
<@-- /ko -->
```

The columns come out great.  But here's the problem:  in the `sort` handler, MyList is undefined.  MySubList is, too.  Since MyList was not undefined for the other `<th>` above, my guess is that the ko foreach has introduced a new scope.  MyList is in scope at the actual foreach statement, of course, because `data` is valid as `subList`.  So, I'm looking for a way to pass a good reference to MyList into `sort`.

Is this enough to go on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your in a loop you have changed scope so you need to access the parent scope from the loop, that might help:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: MyList()[0].MySubList, as: 'subList' -->
<th data-bind="sort: { myArray: $parent.MyList, myProperty: 'SomeSubListProperty' }">  </th>
<@-- /ko -->
```